# setTorchModeOnWithLevel from string

Tags: swift

My var:

```
var torchLevel : Float = 0.0
```

My toggle function:

```
func toggleFlash() {
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        if (device.hasTorch){
            device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On)
            {
                device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
                isTorchOn = 0
            }
            else
            {
                device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(torchLevel, error: nil)
                isTorchOn = 1
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }
```

Change Slider:

```
@IBAction func brightnessSliderAction(sender: UISlider) {
        var currentBrightnessValue = Int(sender.value)
        torchLevel = currentBrightnessValue
        valueLabel.text = "\(torchLevel)"
    }
```

Error in code:

`torchLevel = currentBrightnessValue`

Error message:

> Cannot assign a value of type "int" to a value of type "Float"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `torchLevel` to Float.

Or make it float explicitly like so :

`var torchLevel : Float = 0.0`

Comment: Replace the hole code with just `torchLevel = sender.value`

Comment: You also should note, that torchLevel must be between 0.0 and 1.0 so don't forget to clamp sender.value if it possibly can be lower or bigger.

Comment: Thanks. But since the force strengt goes from 0.1 min, and 1.0 max, how can i do this using a slider?

Comment: UISlider has  `minimumValue` and `maximumValue` that speak for themselves.

Comment: Yes just found out. But if the slider is at 0 and i start the flashlight, the app crashes.. EDIT: Fixed it using a "if value == 0"

Comment: Marked as answer. How can i make it strobe?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the word 'strobe' and translator still tells me nothing.

Comment: How can i make the light blink?

Comment: You should raise a new question for that.